# How to add a return sector to an already booked ticket with Wizz Air?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, dubai, bucharest, wizz-air

How to add a return sector to an already booked ticket with Wizz Air? I booked just one way and if I buy a separate ticket for return there is a huge price difference.

Comment: Ring them up and ask them?

Comment: their call centre seems not to work, i tried couple times. And on their website there is no answer to my situation...

Answer (score 3):

WizzAir is a so-called [low-cost carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_low-cost_airlines). With them the price of a return is the sum of two single tickets. You won't get an extra discount if you book a return ticket.

So as to get cheap tickets, you have to book as early as possible. And/or you have to be flexible with your travel dates. However, if you are late and not flexible, there is not much you can do.

Comment: It was my impression but did you check that yourself? The question seem to suggest that it's not the case (anymore?)

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem is that prices can change from one day to another. A low fare that you see today might not be available anymore tomorrow.

Comment: Might be useful to explain that a little more clearly, then.

Comment: @Relaxed I understood the answer.

Comment: @mkennedy Me too, obviously, if you read my earlier comment. What I could not make out is whether it was written from general knowledge and how it addressed the question. Since Andre confirmed that Wizz Air is in fact a run-of-the-mill LCC, the logical conclusion is that the OP is apparently confused about how they work, so the answer ought to be more explicit.